# Set the min/max date of DatePicker Control in Silverlihgt

Tags: silverlight, datepicker

I used `DatePicker-Control` in my Silverlight project.

How to set the `Max Date` of `DatePicker`.

e.g. If the max date is 12/31/9998, and then we can not input the year which later than 9999 in `DatePicker-Control`.

We just want to restraint the max date which inputed in the `DatePicker`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [DatePicker.DisplayDateEnd Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datepicker.displaydateend%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

To prevent inputting wrong date you can implement [INotifyDataErrorInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifydataerrorinfo%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). [More Info.](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/data-networking/validation/implementing-data-validation-in-silverlight-with-inotifydataerrorinfo)

Comment: Thanks for you answer. But, I have tried this Property, It works. But this can not restraint the input in the input box of DatePicker control. Date more than the max date can be inputed into the input box.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:
[Handling Start and End dates with Custom DatePicker Control](http://www.infosysblogs.com/microsoft/2008/07/silverlight_handling_start_and.html)